# Рисование на JavaFX Canvas

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

Создал что-то по типу Paint'a на Canvas но столкнулся с проблемой - если слишком быстро вести курсор, то фигуры рисуются отрывчато:

[image: демонстрация проблемы]

Можно ли это исправить, чтобы линия была без пробелов, как в Paint'e? Реализация рисования:

```
canvas.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {//логика рисования
    gc.setFill(cp.getValue());//определям цвет

    if(brushType.equals("Square")) {
        gc.fillRect(mouseEvent.getX()-brushSize, mouseEvent.getY()-brushSize, brushSize, brushSize);//рисуем

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent1 -> gc.fillRect(mouseEvent1.getX()-brushSize, mouseEvent1.getY()-brushSize, brushSize, brushSize));//рисуем, если курсор двинулся
    }
    else if(brushType.equals("Circle")){
        gc.fillOval(mouseEvent.getX()-brushSize, mouseEvent.getY()-brushSize, brushSize, brushSize);//рисуем

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent1 -> gc.fillOval(mouseEvent1.getX()-brushSize, mouseEvent1.getY()-brushSize, brushSize, brushSize));//рисуем, если курсор двинулся
    }
});
```

Comment: Не претендую на правильный ответ, никогда не делал графических редакторов в JavaFX, но думаю она слабо под это предназначена. В том же Photoshop тоже есть такой эффект, только наблюдается при очень большом приближении, и сглаживается настройками. Для рисования, всё же, нужно в GLSL лезть. Могу быть очень неправ, если что меня поправят.

Comment: Впрочем, вот возможно [выход](https://www.cyberforum.ru/java-gui/thread1637392.html). Код как у Вас, `setOnMOuseDragged` и тоже не хватает `onMousePressed(MouseEvent)` из [ответа](https://www.cyberforum.ru/post10131182.html). Ссылки на сторонний ресурс.

Comment: Спасибо, мне вполне подходит такой вариант.

Comment: оформите в ответ? На случай если ресурс по ссылкам будет недоступен, возможно кому-то этот ответ тоже поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогло добавление отдельного кода, в котором при движении мыши рисуется линия от прошлого положения курсора к следующему:

```
canvas.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent1 -> {
    gc.lineTo(mouseEvent1.getX(), mouseEvent1.getY());

    gc.stroke();

    gc.moveTo(MouseDragEvent.getX(), MouseDragEvent.getY());
});//рисуем, если курсор двинулся
```

Вот как реализовал в програме:

```
canvas.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {//логика рисования
    gc.setFill(cp.getValue());//определям цвет
    gc.setStroke(cp.getValue());
    gc.setLineWidth(brushSize);//определяем размер

    if(brushType.equals("Square")) {
        gc.fillRect(mouseEvent.getX()-brushSize, mouseEvent.getY()-brushSize, brushSize, brushSize);//рисуем
    }
    else if(brushType.equals("Circle")){
        gc.fillOval(mouseEvent.getX()-brushSize, mouseEvent.getY()-brushSize, brushSize, brushSize);//рисуем
    }
    else if(brushType.equals("Pencil")) {
        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent1 -> {
            gc.lineTo(mouseEvent1.getX(), mouseEvent1.getY());

            gc.stroke();
        });//рисуем, если курсор двинулся
    }

    gc.moveTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());//обновляем положение курсора, чтобы при следующем нажатии мыши не было лишней линии
});
```